# File is missing when trying to upload a model through API doing a PUT request - Multipart/form-data Requests - Laravel / PHP

Tags: php, laravel, api, laravel-5, file-upload

I'm using **Laravel** for the backend for an Android app.

I want to update the user picture, but when uploading the file + additional data to my backend, the file is missing in the request:

```php
dd($request->hasFile('avatar')); // false
dd($request->File('avatar')); // null
```

This is what I sent in **Postman** (by the way i'm using **Passport**):

```php
// Headers
Accept: application/json
Authorization: Bearer {{token}}
Content-Type: multipart/form-data

// Body of the request
'avatar' -> the image (in postman)
```

This is some of my update method, the part that manage the file:

```php
public function update(Request $request)
{
    // ...

    if($request->hasFile('avatar')) 
    {
        $avatar = $request->file('avatar');
        $filename = time() . '.' . $avatar->getClientOriginalExtension();
        Image::make($avatar)->resize(300,300)->save('/path/' . $filename));
        $user->avatar = $filename;
    }

    // ...

    $user->save();

    // ...
}
```

I don't know what am I doing wrong. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you try `var_dump` on `$request-&gt;all()` Maybe your file wasn't sent properly?

Comment: @shalvah It return empty. Now, i'm trying doing this in a POST request and it works. The PUT method seems to be the problem.

Comment: Oh. You never mentioned that it was PUT. I'm not sure files are meant to be uploaded with PUT, and even if they are, they may not automatically get parsed into the request body by Laravel.

Comment: Yeah, it seems to be and old -and unresolved- issue of Symphony according to this: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/13457

Comment: Try using `POST` instead of `PUT` method

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After some research, I could make it work but using a `POST` Request adding `_method = PUT` as param (`http://www.someurl.dev?_method=PUT`). 
PUT request with files aren't handle properly -if i'm not wrong- [on purpose](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.put-method.php)

Anyway, is not the solution that I was looking.. but at least work.

Comment: Oh my gosh this was soooo the problem I was having and I didnt even realize it. I was using `PUT` and trying to upload for almost 24 hours!! Then finally I changed to `POST` and it worked! Thanks for this question and solution! i actually upvoted a couple days ago but forgot to put this comment.